# Alternative of `requestBodyAndHeaders`

Tags: spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

Is there any alternate of camel `requestBodyAndHeaders` in spring? I know about `requestbody` and `requestheader` annotations that can be used but is there a one line solution?

Answer (score 0):

There's no single line solution. @RequestBody and @RequestHeader are available as separate in spring.